# Objective-c TCP/IP client

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a TCP server running on a machine. (implemented in Java). I need to connect to that server from a iPhone and send data to the server and also, receive data on the iphone when server pushes me data. So I need to be notified when data pushes from the server.

Is there a way to do this in Objective C(socket programming). Although I googled I couldn't find a solution. But I saw CFSocket etc.
Please anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after a possible solutions in the internet, I found a nice asynchronous TCP and UDP socket Library here. ([http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/)). This library worked really well for me so far. This wraps the CFSocket and CFStream.

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: CocoaAsyncSocket has moved to github: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CFNetwork family of classes to implement lower level sockets. Apple has an [introduction document](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/networking/conceptual/cfnetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html) that describes the use of these classes.

Answer (score 0):

CFSocket calls and similar will let you create sockets. You can then use CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket() to create a CFReadStreamRef and CFWriteStreamRef, which you can cast to NSInputStream* and NSOutputStream*.